# Fonts in browsers seem to be rendered differently than in the rest of Kubuntu

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, fonts, subpixel-rendering

A simple question really... I have Kubuntu 14.04 installed. The fonts in Google Chrome, Chromium, and Firefox look significantly different than in the rest of the system. Why? I do like how the rest of the fonts are being rendered. Can I get the fonts in my browsers look like the rest?

Here a screenshot that would explain it. On the left, it is a newer version of Chrome. And on the right an older one which I definitely prefer. The fonts are sleek and sharp: [image]

Comment: Can you add screen shots of both variants?

Comment: I did. Please do take a look.

Comment: The right one has a wrong gamma at least for my monitor - do you see some green tint around letters too? (not so important, but worth fixing)

Answer (score 1):

First, go to the Kubuntu font settings,
see how different settings work for
**antialiasing**, **subpixel rendering**, and **hinting**.

That was the minimal set of important font options.

If you want to see the maximal set of font options, try [`infinality`](http://www.infinality.net/blog/):

You need the ppa `ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa`
For how to use it, and important notes to read before, see [launchpad: Better font rendering ppa](https://launchpad.net/~no1wantdthisname/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Install is with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality
```

See `/etc/profile.d/infinality-settings.sh` for setup.

```
$ grep -Eo '^export INFINALITY_[^=]+=' /etc/profile.d/infinality-settings.sh | sort -u
export INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_HORIZONTAL_STEM_DARKEN_STRENGTH=
export INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_INCREASE_GLYPH_HEIGHTS=
export INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_SNAP_STEM_HEIGHT=
export INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_VERTICAL_STEM_DARKEN_STRENGTH=
export INFINALITY_FT_BOLD_EMBOLDEN_X_VALUE=
export INFINALITY_FT_BOLD_EMBOLDEN_Y_VALUE=
export INFINALITY_FT_BRIGHTNESS=
export INFINALITY_FT_CHROMEOS_STYLE_SHARPENING_STRENGTH=
export INFINALITY_FT_CONTRAST=
export INFINALITY_FT_FILTER_PARAMS=
export INFINALITY_FT_FRINGE_FILTER_STRENGTH=
export INFINALITY_FT_GAMMA_CORRECTION=
export INFINALITY_FT_GLOBAL_EMBOLDEN_X_VALUE=
export INFINALITY_FT_GLOBAL_EMBOLDEN_Y_VALUE=
export INFINALITY_FT_GRAYSCALE_FILTER_STRENGTH=
export INFINALITY_FT_STEM_ALIGNMENT_STRENGTH=
export INFINALITY_FT_STEM_FITTING_STRENGTH=
export INFINALITY_FT_STEM_SNAPPING_SLIDING_SCALE=
export INFINALITY_FT_USE_KNOWN_SETTINGS_ON_SELECTED_FONTS=
export INFINALITY_FT_USE_VARIOUS_TWEAKS=
export INFINALITY_FT_WINDOWS_STYLE_SHARPENING_STRENGTH=
```